# How do you make lambda a symbol when importing all Sympy functions?

Tags: python, sympy

If I import sympy with:

```
from sympy import *
```

Then how do set lambda to be a symbol and not a function?

E.g.

```
lambda = symbols('lambda')
```

In my case, likely because sympy has all its functions imported (I am working in a sympy only environment so it is convenient), I receive the error:

```
lambda = symbols('lambda')
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to avoid this **if** I am importing all the functions from sympy?

Thank you

Comment: Because `lambda` is a privileged keyword in Python, there is a convention o use 'lamda` (without the 'b') as a variable name.  See e.g. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4859

Comment: That makes sense thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `lambda` is a keyword for creating lambda functions. You can't use it as your variable name. You'll have to find a new name. Even if you find a way to assign `lambda` to something, it won't work because it's not parsed as a potential variable name.

For example:

```
lambda_ = symbols('lambda')
```

will not have the same error.